# Injections are stopping after adding @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, dependency-injection, transactions, guice

I have created a class that makes easy to add and update Employees. I have added `@Transactional` annotation to the createEmployee method, then my instances started to give error while I try to retrieve data.

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void createEmployee(Employee employee) {
        internalCreateEmployee(employee);
    }
```

without @Transactional everything works but I can save anything to the database. When I add this annotation I got this error.

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
>   rd.EmployeeManagerImpl.(Lrd./EmployeeDao;Lrd./DepartmentDao;)V
>   from class rd.EmployeeManagerImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$5db9fd74

Inside the EmployeemanagerImpl I am also injecting my DAO objects in the constructor.

```
    @Inject
    EmployeeManagerImpl(EmployeeDao employeeDao, DepartmentDao departmentDao){
        this.employeeDao = employeeDao;
        this.departmentDao = departmentDao;
    }
```

What can be the reason for that @Transactional breaks things?

I just don't know which information is necessary to provide, If you need any further information just ask.

Note: `Employee` is a hibernate entity class. `EmployeeDao`, `DepartmentDao` and `EmployeeManagerImpl` are all have the `@Singleton` annotation.

Note2: In the stack trace, It seems like EmployeeManager instance can't be initialized.

```
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    org.apache.wicket.guice.GuiceProxyTargetLocator.locateProxyTarget(GuiceProxyTargetLocator.java:105)
    org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:430)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.getDepartmentList(Unknown Source)
    rd.EmployeeFormComponent.addDepartmentDropDown(EmployeeFormComponent.java:59)
    rd.EmployeeFormComponent.<init>(EmployeeFormComponent.java:47)
    rd.EmployeeAddPanel.<init>(EmployeeAddPanel.java:61)
    rd.EmployeeAddModalWindow$1.<init>(EmployeeAddModalWindow.java:20)
    rd.EmployeeAddModalWindow.<init>(EmployeeAddModalWindow.java:20)
    rd.ManageEmployeePage$1.<init>(ManageEmployeePage.java:49)
    rd.ManageEmployeePage.<init>(ManageEmployeePage.java:49)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are injecting `EmployeeManager` twice that could be the problem. I am guessing that `EmployeeFormComponent` is a `Wicket Component`. Wicket has its own Guice Injector for its components. So if you are injecting your `EmployeeManager` with `@Inject` and if you try to attempt inject with something else as well, this means you inject it twice. This might cause a problem like that.

Comment: But it should't work for the other case as well, right. When I remove @Transactional it works despite the fact that it is injected in many places.

Comment: No you got me wrong. It is okay to have multiple injections in different places. Transactional is something that happens for only that action. Check if you are injecting twice in the component class.

Comment: Oh my god. I didn't expect that solution was that easy. Yes I am using another annotation to inject services on the UI. I guess it was conflicting with the Wicket. Now it is working.

Answer (score 3):

When you add the `@Transactional` annotation, a proxy class will be generated to handle the transaction magic. It appears the proxy class is unable to call the EmployeeManager constructor due to access restrictions. I would try making the constructor public.

Comment: The same problem still persists.

Comment: The IllegalAccessError still exists, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but in the root cause com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors. - So the reason was multiple injections in the component class.